# Using subquery in named query where clause

Tags: java, mysql, eclipselink, named-query

I have this named query (simplified a little [removed some date filters], to be more clear at first sight):

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@AdditionalCriteria("this.deleted <> 'deleted'")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "FacilityForm.findByDateFacility", query = "SELECT f FROM FacilityForm f WHERE f.formDate BETWEEN :from and :to AND f.id In (SELECT o.id from InventoryLog l, FormItem i, FacilityForm o WHERE (:facilityId IS NULL OR i.facilityId = :facilityId) AND l.formItemId = i.id AND i.formId = o.id) ORDER BY f.formDate DESC")
})
```

Extracted query string:

```
"SELECT f FROM FacilityForm f WHERE f.formDate BETWEEN :from and :to AND f.id In (SELECT o.id from InventoryLog l, FormItem i, FacilityForm o WHERE (:facilityId IS NULL OR i.facilityId = :facilityId) AND l.formItemId = i.id AND i.formId = o.id) ORDER BY f.formDate DESC"
```

I know that if I want to use the main Entity in also one subquery I have to use another alias for it, I believe I done that (with: FacilityForm o in the subquery).

My problem is, that I get this error when calling it up on my form:

```
Info:   ERROR APPNAME - Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.ID)) AND (t2.FORM_ID = t1.ID.t1.ID)) AND (t3.DELETED <> 'deleted')) AND ((t2.DE' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: 
SELECT t0.ID, t0.FORM_TYPE, t0.BANK_ACCOUNT_NO, t0.BANK_NAME, t0.COMMENT_BOTTOM, t0.COMMENT_UP, t0.COMPANY_ID, t0.CREATED_BY, t0.CREATED_TS, t0.CURRENCY, t0.DAILY_RATE, t0.DELETED, t0.DELIVERY_DATE, t0.DIRECTION, t0.EMAIL_SENT, t0.EU_INTERNAL_BOO, t0.FOREIGN_LANG_BOO, t0.FORM_DATE, t0.FORM_NR, t0.IBAN, t0.MODIFIED_BY, t0.MODIFIED_TS, t0.PAYMENT_BOOKED, t0.PAYMENT_DATE, t0.PAYMENT_TERM, t0.PAYMENT_TYPE, t0.PRINTED_ORIG, t0.REVERSE_CHARGE_BOO, t0.STATE, t0.STATUS, t0.SUBTYPE, t0.SWIFT, t0.TITLE, t0.TYPE, t0.USER_ID, t0.VERSION, t0.ADDRESS_DATA_ID, t0.ADDRESS_ID, t0.CONTACT_ID, t0.CONTAINER_ID_FROM, t0.CONTAINER_ID_TO, t0.FACILITY_ID_FROM, t0.FACILITY_ID_TO, t0.JOB_ID, t0.PARTNER_DATA_ID, t0.PARTNER_ID, t0.RELATED_FORM_ID, t0.WS_ORDER_ID FROM form t0 
WHERE (((((((t0.DIRECTION = ?) 
AND (t0.FORM_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?)) AND ((? IS NULL) OR (t0.MODIFIED_TS >= ?))) AND ((? IS NULL) OR (t0.MODIFIED_TS <= ?))) AND (t0.STATUS > ?)) AND t0.ID IN (SELECT t1.ID FROM inventory_log t3, form_item t2, form t1 WHERE ((((((? IS NULL) OR (t2.FACILITY_ID = ?)) AND (t3.FORM_ITEM_ID = t2.ID.t2.ID)) AND (t2.FORM_ID = t1.ID.t1.ID)) AND (t3.DELETED <> ?)) AND ((t2.DELETED <> ?) AND ((t1.DELETED <> ?) AND (t1.FORM_TYPE = ?)))))) AND ((t0.DELETED <> ?) AND (t0.FORM_TYPE = ?))) ORDER BY t0.FORM_DATE DESC
    bind => [16 parameters bound]
```

Relevant part:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.ID)) AND (t2.FORM_ID = t1.ID.t1.ID)) AND (t3.DELETED <> 'deleted')) AND ((t2.DE' at line 1
```

Can somebody please help me, what could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: t1.ID.t1.ID printing off is a bug, but its hard to tell why it is getting confused. Try the queries separately and verify they work and the SQL is as expected. The main query has some clauses "AND ((? IS NULL) OR (t0.MODIFIED_TS >= ?))) AND ((? IS NULL) OR (t0.MODIFIED_TS <= ?))) AND (t0.STATUS > ?))" , and the 'deleted' checks that we can't see where they would come from using the JPQL you've shown.

Comment: The “deleted” comes from the beginning at the @AdditionalCriteria. I removed the modified dates from the query to be more simple. The two queries are working fine, I checked them first. So I assume it must be something with the namedquery